# Add TextViews programmatically to a XML Layout

Tags: android, layout, textview

This is a `XML LinearLayout linlayout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mylinear"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to add `TextViews` to this layout programmatically because the number of `TextViews` to be added can be different sometimes.

Here is the activity code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.linlayout);

    LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.mylinear);
    TextView [] txt =new TextView[3];

    for(int i=0;i<txt.length;i++)
    {
        txt[i]=new TextView(this);
        txt[i].setText("text "+i);
        txt[i].setLayoutParams(new
         LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linear.addView(txt[i]);
    }
}
```

The `LogCat` don't display errors but the `TextViews` are not displayed when I run the app.

I try to put the line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.linlayout);
```

at the end, after the `for`, but doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check if the color of your text view's text isn't the same as the background color of your layout?

Comment: check by removing  TextView txt =new TextView[3];

Comment: TextView txt =new TextView[3];  change this line by TextView txt =new TextView[this];

Comment: TextView [] txt =new TextView[3]; This is an array of 3 TextViews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this :

```
TextView [] txt = new TextView[3];

for (int i=0; i<txt.length; i++) {
    txt[i] = new TextView(YourActivity.this);
    txt[i].setText("text " + i);
    txt[i].setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams
    (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear.addView(txt[i]);
}
```

Comment: In my code this is Ok, just an error when I write the post, I edited it, sorry.

Comment: I copied your code and paste in my application it works fine.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks, Using txt[i]=new TextView(YourActivity.this); works fine.

Comment: if this works fine. Then you have to accept this as right answer.

Comment: i am trying to add TextView progmmatically, but it does not work.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
  RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
  final TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
  
  tv.setText("Hello World");
  tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  rl.addView(tv);  
  
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use a ListView. By the way did you change the orientation of your layout to a vertical orientation ? But if it necessary for you i suggesst this : 
i suppose you have an element with a certain size.

```
final int size = 3; // replace with the size of your element
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.mylinear);

for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("text "+i);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    linear.addView(textView);
}
```