# Container for multiple text views that joins and wraps

Tags: android, textview, containers

Is it possible to do something like this:

[image]

Where I can add `n` amount of `TextViews` at runtime to the container, in order, and it will wrap them like in the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12837405

You can use a `LinearLayout` instead of `TextView`, then add the `Textview`s in the `LinearLayout` and when you've set the layout params add the LinearLayout to the main Layout.

Comment: The problem is that this would not wrap, or join like I want.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.